# API call in react from user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to build a simple weather application. I need to get an input from the user and then submit it. The following code below doesn't work as required. Can someone please help as I am beginner

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    search: ''
  }
  inputSubmitHandler = (e) => {
      this.setState({
          search: e.target.value
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form >
            <input  onChange={this.inputSubmitHandler}/>
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <Weather search={this.state.search}/> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to get the full input only after the user clicks submit, and then change the state and then pass it to the Weather component.

Edit: Here is the Weather component to make things more clear

```
class Weather extends Component {
    state = {
        temp: null,
        humidity: null,
    }

    Getweather = (search) => {
        axios.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=d0c1e9b30aef451789b152051200907&q='+search)
            .then(res => {
                const tempr = res.data.current.temp_c;
                const humidity = res.data.current.humidity;
                this.setState({
                    temp: tempr,
                    humidity: humidity,
                })
                // console.log(res);
            })
    }

    

    render() {
        this.Getweather(this.props.search)
        return (
            <div>   
                {this.state.temp}
                {this.state.humidity}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to update state only after pressing the button, you should probably change the event handler from `onChange` to `onSubmit` of the form

Comment: I tried that..but e.target.value doesn't work  ig

Answer (score 0):

Your this code is fine:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ search: e.target.value });  // This will update the input value in state
}
```

and then you can try:

```
<form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
```

and define the `submitHandler` like:

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();  // It will hold the form submit
    console.log('state:', this.state.search);
    // You will get the updated state ( the one that yo have updated on onChange event listener ) here, make your api call here with the updated state
}
```

**Issue:**

```
<Weather search={this.state.search}/>
```

Here you are passing the state instantly and that's why it starts sending requests continuously.

Comment: Its already working in `handleChange`, just create the `submitHandler` and your code will work as per your requirement

Comment: I tried it and yes, it now prints the state as expected in the console. However, i think there's something wrong in the ```<Weather search={this.state.search}/>``` part because as soon as i input anything, it starts sending requests continously

Comment: Because you are doing it wrong, call the API in submit handler, check the updated ans

Comment: I have added the weather component to the question..what changes should i make now...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you need two different variables: (1) the input variable (search) and then a buffered variable which is filled when the button is clicked:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
   this.state = { search: '', clippedSearch: null }
  }

  onChange(ev) {
    this.setState({ search: ev.target.value })
  }

  onSubmit(ev) {
    this.setState({ clippedSearch: this.state.search })
  } 

  render() {
   return <div>
     <form>
       <input type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={onChange} />
       <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>

       <Weather search={this.state.clippedSearch} />
     </form>
   </div>
  }
}
```